# Integer division which results in less than 1

Tags: c, integer, division

How we can use scale factor of 1000 for example to not get 0 to a as we work with integers. Its on 32bit microcontroller.

Example:

```
uint32 a;
a = 211/555 * x;
```

Should we just multiply everything on right by 1000, and then divide final result with 1000?

Comment: do `(211 * x) / 555`

Comment: Cast one of the operands to `float`/`double`?

Comment: Hmmm. Isn't that basic school math?

Comment: @Jabberwocky you are right, but just want to see other people opinion, because I went with scaling factor, but also rearranging elements looks much easier.

Comment: Assuming positive values, if you want to **round** the result you can add half of `555` before the division to be approximately right: `(211 * x + 277) / 555` which is `(211 * x / 555) + (277 / 555)`.

Comment: Any form of finite-precision arithmetic (integer, fixed, floating) will give an approximation of the real number 211/555•x, except when there happens to be some coincidence between the numbers and the format (e.g., if `x` is 111, then 211/555•x could be calculated exactly with decimal arithmetic if done properly). So a question you need to consider is **what** answer is acceptable in place of 211/555•x? Is it okay to truncate, or do you want rounding to the nearest integer (maximum error ½)? Is more error acceptable, or do you need even less than ½? Answer that before considering methods.

Comment: @TicTacToe: So truncation is not okay, you need rounding? Then `x*211/555` is insufficient; you need `(x*211+555/2) / 555`.

Comment: problem with (211 * x) / 555 is that if numerator is too big for an integer you get overflow. There isn't a perfect solution for all value ranges

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may apply the scale factor before doing the division.

In your example you are effectively doing (assuming that x=1000)

```
a = (211/555) * x;
```

which will turn out to be

```
a = 0*x;
```

If you change it around to

```
a =(x*211)/555;
```

you can force the multiplication first, creating a numerator larger than 555 which will allow a to be greater than 0.

You cannot then divide this result by 1000 though because it will still be less than 0 which cannot be stored in an integer data type.

You need to keep it in this form and always treat that number as having a 1000 multiplier (for example if the units were originally kilometers, the new number is in meters) or you will have to use a type which can handle numbers less than 1 (like a float or double).

Comment: Good idea, but also multiplying everything by 1000, and then divide result 1000 is ok, as at the end the results is the same.

Comment: No. Dividing by 1000 at the end is still going to give you a number less than 1 at the end.

((1000*211)/555) /1000 still comes out to 211/555 in the end which is a number between 0 and 1 and therefore cannot be held in an integer type.

Comment: ((211/555)*1000*380*1000))/1000000. I think this is also valid.

Comment: @TicTacToe `(211/555)` is still going to give you `0` as before.

Comment: @TicTacToe if this is the correct answer please accept it as correct.